# Airport with Málaga Travel Card

Tags: public-transport, airports, europe, spain, malaga

I am planning to buy the **Metro de Málaga Travel Card** for travelling within Malaga. As described [here](https://metromalaga.es/en/tickets-and-fares/), the price per trip is around 0.41 euros.

Can I also pay using the same card while buying a ticket for the airport bus? A single ticket for the airport bus (without the travel card) costs 4 euros. But what if I am using the card to pay for it? Will I still be charged 4 euros per person?

https://www.malagatop.com/en/how-to-get-to-malaga/getting-to-from-malaga-airport/

Comment: Just a comment. As well as the  Metro de Málaga Travel Card there is the Transport Consortium Travel Card: It explicitly says it is for all public transport. The Metro card does not, so surely the assumption must be it is for the Metro only.